# How do I optimize this query further?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am attempting to optimize this query. I'm a little stumped as to how to make it cost less for the estimated subtree cost in the estimated execution plan. The result typically returns on average 50k rows and takes longer than I would like. Any time shaved would be useful. Thanks.

```
SELECT
    tbl1.DID AS "CID",
    tbl1.ID AS "ID",

    tbl2.Column2 AS "Col2",
    tbl2.Column3 AS "Col3",

    tbl3.Column4 AS "Col4",
    tbl3.Column5 AS "Col5",

    tbl4.Column6 AS "Col6"
FROM TABLE1 tbl1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN TABLE2 tbl2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.CID
INNER JOIN TABLE3 tbl3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON tbl1.ID = tbl3.CID 
INNER JOIN TABLE4 tbl4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON tbl1.DID = tbl4.CID
```

Update - Primary key info. All columns in the inner join for each table have indexes already. If a primary key then it looks like the one below otherwise it's a non-clustered like the one at the bottom.:
The primary key indexes look like this.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[IDX_TABLE1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON  [PRIMARY]
```

The other column indexes that are non-clustered look like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_TABLE1] ON [dbo].[TABLE1] 
(
[DID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE1](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[DID] [int] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE2](
[CID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Column3] [varchar](50) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE3](
[CID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Column4] [varchar](50) NULL
    [Column5] [varchar](50) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,  ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE4](
[CID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Column6] [char](2) NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_TABLE4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect? I. e. which database system? Could you post a plan?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the foreign keys?

Comment: Do you have any index on the columns you are comparing each other?

Comment: It's important to know the bandwidth of your network between database and client. 50k rows might mean, that transferring the result set is the main time consumer.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.  What you have shown us is not a table definition.

Comment: SQL 2008. Those columns on the INNER JOIN statements already have indexes. For the ones that are primary keys they are clustered and for the columns that are not primary keys they are non-clustered.

Comment: Based on what little you've shown us so far, you need to put indexes on the [CID] columns in tables 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: Those do have indexes. I continue to update the info above.

Comment: Why are you using the `NOLOCK` hint? Do you know that the query may return wrong results when you use it? Have you tried removing it? How much time does the query take to execute? Can you provide the execution plan?

Comment: Are there foreign key constraints between these tables?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure there is an index on the join column of each table. In SQL Server you can also create a "covering index" by using the INCLUDE option and put all columns used in your query in there. That way only the index gets read and the query never goes to the table for data.

Like this:

```
create index idx_name
on tbl2 (cid)
include (Column2, Column3)
```

based on the additional information, you need the index on tbl2 and one on tbl3 that is similar to the above.

```
create index idx_name1
on tbl3 (cid)
include (Column4, Column5)
```

This should help some with the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you provided, the right approach to solving this will be to select the entire query, right-click on that selection, and choose "Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor". It will give you some ideas on how to optimize it.

There is no way we can optimize this without significant knowledge of the schema, execution plan, **and** the current run time. We would further need knowledge of the hardware it's running on.

Generally speaking the tuning advisor will give you insight into what changes you could make to the underlying schema to produce a faster result. It will also tell you how much of an improvement you should see (e.g. 98%).